# How can I speed up my Entity Framework LINQ Query?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

Sorry for such a generic question.. I am using Entity & LINQ to query a table (Model) called `Patient.` My goal is use JqueryUI's autocomplete to assist in an ASP.Net MVC 5 suggested search text bar in which you may use a string for patient name, but also their Key in the same box. Here is my Model:

```
public partial class Patient
{
    public Patient()
    {
        PickupExchange = new HashSet<PickupExchange>();
        SalesOrder2 = new HashSet<SalesOrder2>();
    }

    public int PtKey { get; set; }
    public int? PatientId { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string BillingAddress1 { get; set; }
    public string BillingAddress2 { get; set; }
    public string BillingCity { get; set; }
    public string BillingState { get; set; }
    public string BillingZip { get; set; }
    public string BillingPhone { get; set; }
    public string Faxnumber { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string MobilePhone { get; set; }
    public string Suffix { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Dob { get; set; }
    public string Ssn { get; set; }
    public string HoldAcct { get; set; }
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public string AccountGrp { get; set; }
    public string Sex { get; set; }
    public decimal? Height { get; set; }
    public decimal? Weight { get; set; }
    public string MaritalStatus { get; set; }
    public string Employment { get; set; }
    public byte? DiscountPct { get; set; }
    public byte? BranchKey { get; set; }
    public string DelivAddress1 { get; set; }
    public string DelivAddress2 { get; set; }
    public string DelivCity { get; set; }
    public string DelivState { get; set; }
    public string DelivZip { get; set; }
    public string DelivPhone { get; set; }
    public string User1 { get; set; }
    public string User2 { get; set; }
    public string User3 { get; set; }
    public string User4 { get; set; }
    public string EclastName { get; set; }
    public string EcfirstName { get; set; }
    public string EcmiddleName { get; set; }
    public string Ecaddress1 { get; set; }
    public string Ecaddress2 { get; set; }
    public string Eccity { get; set; }
    public string Ecstate { get; set; }
    public string EcpostalCode { get; set; }
    public string EcphoneNum { get; set; }
    public string Ecfax { get; set; }
    public string Ecemail { get; set; }
    public string Rprelationship { get; set; }
    public string RplastName { get; set; }
    public string RpfirstName { get; set; }
    public string RpmiddleName { get; set; }
    public string Rpaddress1 { get; set; }
    public string Rpaddress2 { get; set; }
    public string Rpcity { get; set; }
    public string Rpstate { get; set; }
    public string RppostalCode { get; set; }
    public string RpphoneNum { get; set; }
    public string Rpfax { get; set; }
    public string Rpemail { get; set; }
    public string HippasignatureOnFile { get; set; }
    public string TaxZone { get; set; }
    public string BillingCounty { get; set; }
    public string DeliveryCounty { get; set; }
    public int? ReferralKey { get; set; }
    public string ReferralType { get; set; }
    public short? CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreateDt { get; set; }
    public string NickName { get; set; }
    public string AutoChargeCc { get; set; }
    public string SarautoPayStatus { get; set; }
    public string SareDeliveryStatus { get; set; }
    public string SarpaymentPlan { get; set; }
    public string Sarinformation { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdateDt { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Dod { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is my SQL Table containing all the Patient Data is absolutely huge.  I am using my LINQ query to return a TOP 10 as json back to my javasript function:

```
 var alreadyRunning = false;
 patientID.bind('input', function () {
    if (alreadyRunning == false) {
        alreadyRunning = true;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Controller/Model',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                patientID: patientID.val()
            },
            success(data) {
                patientID.autocomplete({
                    source: data
                });
                alreadyRunning = false;
            }
            , failure(data) {
                alert("Error Searching Value: " + patientID.val());
                alreadyRunning = false;
            }
            , error(data) {
                alert("Error Searching Value: " + patientID.val());
                alreadyRunning = false;
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        patientID.autocomplete({
            source: ["None"]
        });
    }
```

This LINQ query keeps timing out and I can't find a way to speed up the query.. am I doing something wrong or is my data set just too large?

```
  ptTable = int.TryParse(patientID, out number) ?
        btd.Patient.Where(x => x.Database == "databaseName" && x.PatientId.ToString().StartsWith(number.ToString())).OrderBy(x => x.LastName).Take(10).ToList() :
        btd.Patient.Where(x => x.Database == "databaseName" && x.LastName.ToLower() + ", " + x.FirstName.ToLower()).StartsWith(patientID.ToLower()).OrderBy(x => x.LastName).Take(10).ToList();
```

Is it too much string manipulation for SQL to execute quickly?  Any advice would be very beneficial!

Comment: it doesn't matter if you do take 10, because LINQ goes and get all that list anyways first.

Comment: @Valkyriee nope. If you don't execute query before applying sorting - EF will generate  SQL query which will do all the job on server side

Comment: I can confirm this, `.ToLower()`, `.ToString()`, and `.StartsWith()` all translate into one query, at least on my database (SQL Server).  MySQL may behave differently.

Comment: Yes, this certainly is too much string manipulation. The main issue is that you convert database values before searching, which disables indexes. I think at least the first query should be replaced by a range search.

Comment: Also, I can't imagine that you always need the full record. Narrowing down the projection will also help considerably.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Great! i didn't know that :D

Comment: Fix your database, stop relying on string so much thats horrible, the number for your patient should have its own index and specific column for number so you don't have to use a starts with

Comment: @johnny5 if I was in control of the database, I would love to restructure it. : /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you're looking for a way to create an Autocomplete but the query is too slow, and on top of that you have no control over the database.  In that case you should store all the names and patient numbers in memory even if you have a large set of data you should still be able to cache this fine.

```
var lookupData = context.Patients.Select(p =>new { p.LastName, p.patientId}).ToArray();

var lastNames = lookupData.Select(x => x.LastName).ToArray();
var patientId = lookupData.Where(x => null != x.patientId).ToArray();
```

once you have these collection's you can just filter on this:

This way you only have to make a query once, you will however have to add a mechantism to update the cache when adding/removing/updating a patient, but atleast you will only have to do this query once

Comment: If you have a large data set and your worried about searching though such a long enumerable, you can group things by there first initial

Comment: Thank you very much, this is much better solution.

Answer (score 2):

Problem with SQL (MySQL) server is that it stores data in rows. It serializes each row of data and assigns internal row ids. Something like this (from wikipedia):

```
001:10,Smith,Joe,40000;
002:12,Jones,Mary,50000;
003:11,Johnson,Cathy,44000;
004:22,Jones,Bob,55000;
```

In your case each row will contain lot of columns. Row-based systems are good for returning whole row of data. But they are not efficient when you need to filter data, because whole row should be loaded from disc into memory, then required fields can be analyzed. And row-based system will do that for whole table.

You can boost performance by creating indexes for columns which you are using in query. E.g. for `Database` field (and other fields probably).

```
ALTER TABLE Patient ADD INDEX COLUMN_NAME (COLUMN_NAME)
```

In that case (again from wiki) index for some column will look like

```
001:Smith;
003:Jones;
002:Johnson;
004:Jones;
```

So instead of loading all row from disc, database will load only index data. That is much much faster.

If performace still will suck after you will create indexes, consider to use column-oriented database.

Comment: This is very good advice.  Unfortantly, I am not in control the poorly made database that I have access to. : /

Comment: @Rinktacular why did you mark this as the answer if it doesn't solve your problem

Comment: @johnny5 I asked for a faster query and this answer provided that.

Comment: @Rinktacular if you can't modify database, then the only thing which you *can* modify is a query which is sent to database. Your example is pretty simple, so I have doubts that EF generates something inefficient for simple where + orderby + take query. But you can use something like Dapper to execute raw sql instead. Though again, it will not give you good performance boost. Better ask guys which manage database to create indexes for you